# Is there any way to create a stack traceback and log the call stack to a trace log file that will work with visual C++ 6.0?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6, traceback

I have a legacy codebase that has binary-library dependencies on Visual C++ 6.0 and I cannot obtain source code for those binary libraries. So I  am stuck debugging crashes on a Visual C++ 6.0 application.  I notice that [CrashRpt](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/) would be really handy if I could use at least Visual C++ 2005 or later, but since I can't, are there any other choices with at least some kind of global ability to catch faults, and generate a stack trace, if the application terminates via some abnormal fault, or throws an unhandled exception?

I've found some [articles](http://www.howzatt.demon.co.uk/articles/oct04.html) on Structured Exception Handling and the MS Debug Helper dll, but no cooked up working system, that I could simply drop into a VC++6 app.

Comment: So far, after several months, answer is NO you can't. Get off VC++6.